# Why is this appending procedure erroneous - using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 .csv files:

fileA: this has 784 values per line (I have about 60,000 lines).

```
'0,0,0,0,0,0,215,150,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,69,152,143,238,211,136,143,154,89,0,0,0,...,0\n'
```

fileB: this also has 60,000 lines but only 1 value per line

```
'1\n'
```

I want to append this 2 files so fileC would have fileA appended to fileB. I.e. in fileC, fileB's value would be the first value, followed by the rest of (784) values of fileA, for resulting (785 values per line).

ex. fileC

```
'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,215,150,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,69,152,143,238,211,136,143,154,89,0,0,0,...,0\n'
```

I am trying to do this using `pandas` by:

```
a = pd.read_csv("/Users/usr/Images.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("/Users/usr/Labels.csv")
con = pd.concat([a,b],axis=1)
con.to_csv("testCON.csv", index = False)
```

but my resulting .csv file is massive with decimal points:

```
'0,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0,...'
```

How do I do this properly?

edit:
this is what 1 line looks like in fileA:
[image]

this is what my result is:
[image]

Comment: If you want b to come before a, then why do you do [a, b] and not [b, a] in `con = pd.concat([a,b],axis=1)`?

Comment: thats the right thing to do brother

Comment: you probably have decimal points because you have null values somewhere in the data and columns will nulls can't be integers. `NaN` is a float.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ya sorry, but that's just technicality, the result seems to have 1,568 values per line instead of 785. I'm adding a picture now.

Comment: What does  `len(a) == len(b)` give?

Comment: @Bn.F76 - What return `print (a.columns.tolist())` ? If no csv header need `a = pd.read_csv("/Users/usr/Images.csv", header=None)`

Comment: @Bn.F76 - Also it seems all data are in one column

Comment: @Bn.F76 - it seems some data relevant problem, is possible share `csv` files if not confidental?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it gives me `True` . I have a mini-sample of the fileA and B which contain 10 entries each, I can share that but I don't know... should I put it in a DropBox... (or how do I share on here).

Comment: @jezrael if I do `print (a.columns.tolist())` I see `['0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4',...`

Comment: @Bn.F76 - So `header=None` in `read_csv` does not help?

Comment: @jezrael it does, your answer worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `header=None` for read `csv` with no header and then swap `b` and `a` in `concat` as pointed [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967763/why-is-this-appending-procedure-erroneous-using-pandas/49968039#comment86951091_49967763):

```
a = pd.read_csv("csvTestImageSmall10 copy.csv", header=None)
b = pd.read_csv("csvTestLabelSmall10 copy.csv", header=None)
con = pd.concat([b,a],axis=1)
print (con)

con.to_csv("testCON.csv", index = False, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or roll your own without Pandas:

```
import csv
with open("/Users/usr/Images.csv") as a, open("/Users/usr/Labels.csv") as b, open("testCON.csv", 'w') as outfile:
    rdr_a, rdr_b, out = csv.reader(a), csv.reader(b), csv.writer(outfile)
    for line_a, line_b in zip(rdr_a,rdr_b):
        line_b.extend(line_a)
        out.writerow(line_b)
```